# TypeError: Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'

Tags: python, filesystems, python-os, getcwd

```
    import os

directory = os.getcwd


if os.path.exists(directory + "\\token.txt"):
    print('token file aleady exists. terminating token setup')
else:
    tokenfile =  open("token.txt", "x")
```

the error is coming from this line:
if os.path.exists(directory + "\token.txt").
I am not sure how to fix this error. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Python functions must be called with () after the method name.

The correct code you need is:

````
import os
directory = os.getcwd()
if os.path.exists(directory + "\\token.txt"):
 print('token file aleady exists. terminating token setup')```
````